# Как показать все выполненные функции с++

Tags: c++, c

Есть код с функциями. Есть ли какой-либо способ узнать очередность выполнения этих функций?
Т.е. я хочу увидеть что-то вроде такого:

```
main -> func1 star -> func2 start -> func2 end -> funс1 end -> func3 start -> func3 end
```

Можно конечно в начале и конце писать `puts("star/end\n")`. Возможно есть что-то более удобное, или по каким словам это гуглить?

Comment: #define как всегда, но не совсем получится...

Comment: Для этого есть отладчик...

Answer (score 0):

Я когда-то воспользовался (С++ only) классом типа

```
class CallInfo
{
public:
    CallInfo(const char * name):name(name) { cout << name << " start\n"; }
    ~CallInfo() { cout << name << " end\n"; }
private:
    const char * name;
};

#define  Callinfo CallInfo ci__(__func__);

void test()
{
    Callinfo
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Callinfo
    test();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я предполагаю, что список ВСЕХ вызовов Вам не нужен. А, на самом деле, Вам нужен стек вызовов функций в некоей точке, в которой (скорее всего) произошла ошибка и Вы пытаетесь понять, откуда пришло управление.

Для этой цели в с/с++ есть функция backtrace:

> backtrace()  returns a backtrace for the calling program, in the array
>   pointed to by buffer. A backtrace is the series of currently active
>   function calls for the program.  Each item  in the  array pointed to
>   by buffer is of type void *, and is the return address from the
>   corresponding stack frame.  The size argument specifies the maximum
>   number of addresses that  can be stored in buffer.  If the backtrace
>   is larger than size, then the addresses  corresponding to the size
>   most recent function calls are returned; to obtain the complete
>   backtrace,  make sure that buffer and size are large enough.

man 3 backtrace

Comment: Это не "в с/c++", а специфическая функциональность в библиотеке GNU. В С/С++ как таковом ничего подобного нет.

Comment: **В С/С++ как таковом ничего подобного нет.** В языках С/С++ нет НИЧЕГО кроме самого языка. Даже *printf* - это уже не язык, а библиотека.

Comment: `printf` - это функция из *стандартной* библиотеки, спецификация которой является частью спецификации языка (т.е. описывается стандартом языка). Функция `printf` - стандартная функция. Функция `backtrace` стандартной не является.